# How to update single value in local array

Tags: javascript, arrays, local

I keep hearing that global arrays and variables are bad. How do you save values in a local array and access them later, since when the function containing the local array is called the array is overwritten.

Comment: You might want to look into closures.

Comment: o.k.  Just reading up on closures.  So would the best way to store values be to create a new object that holds the values (values I am working with are multiple x y coordinate values, and text values that need to be used for the life of the page)?